# DAMP / Aquia Dev (mac) apache fails on import of drupal core 7

Tags: installation

I'm attempting to switch from Bitnami to Aquia Dev Desktop for the mac (OS 10.8.2). I'd like to be able to develop a couple sites (using core drupal - not the aquia distro) simultaneously in a reliable environment.

1. Ran the uninstaller on Bitnami and checked that all files were
   deleted.
2. I successfully installed Aquia Dev Desktop, saw that Apache and
   MySQL servers were both running, and got the local Aquia Drupal site
   when I clicked "Go to my site" in the control panel. So everything
   was working fine.
3. Downloaded Drupal 7 to a folder on my desktop, decompressed, renamed the drupal
   folder to my site name (all lower case and no special characters),
   and reset the folder permissions to "Read & Write" and applied to
   all enclosed folders.
4. I attempted to import into Aquia Dev Desktop but got "Error -
   Process 'Apache Web Server' failed to start".

I tried using the settings panel in Aquia Dev Desktop to reset port from 8082 to 8080 but apache still won't start.  Tried a few other port numbers and no luck.

Here's the complete Apache error log:

> [Fri Apr 05 15:05:54 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) PHP/5.2.17
>   configured -- resuming normal operations
>  [Fri Apr 05 15:06:37
>   2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>  [Fri Apr 05 15:06:43
>   2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) PHP/5.3.18 configured -- resuming
>   normal operations
>  [Fri Apr 05 15:16:41 2013] [notice] caught
>   SIGTERM, shutting down

I have very little experience with server administration or apache configuration.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Dev Desktop.  The good folks at Acquia fixed the bug and posted a new version that works nicely.